# Unable to generate sitemap.xml for angular 6 build project using Google Sitemap Generator(chrome extension)

Tags: angular6, xml-sitemap

Google sitemap generator generates sitemap.xml file for homepage only in angular 6 build project. Cannot generate for other routing url paths as a whole.

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
<loc>http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/home</loc>
</url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Yeah. I generated the urls manually, I mean in the client side and sent them to the back end side in the form of xml. I know this is not the ultimate solution but it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.

Comment: You are most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add all other pages manually

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
<loc>http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/home/abc</loc>
</url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: Thank you but I needed it automatic.